# MySQL upload CSV file as new table

Tags: mysql

I frequently upload CSV files to a MySQL db.

It is very convenient to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` to upload the data, but I can't use this to create the table itself.  As of now, the best method I have is to use PHP to get the field titles from the first row of the file and then put together a `CREATE table` query.  Is there a more convenient way to do this?

Comment: How can you tell from the CSV data what the types of the MySQL fields should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any automated method would be missing some key information about the table: the types of the columns (although they could be guessed via some heuristics), null/not null, the indexes/primary keys, and foreign key relationships.

If all your columns are VARCHAR, your method is probably the most convenient. Perhaps you could write a wrapper script to automate the process of creating the table and importing the contents (minus the header)?